# Instantiate GameObject function not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to instantiate an object every 40 units (the "Lampadaire" object).
Therefore, when I put this script on an object, and start the game, nothing happens. 
Here is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LampadaireSpawn : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Lampadaire;
    public float Zpos = 10;
    public float InstantiateTime = 0.4f;

    private Quaternion LampadaireLeft = new Quaternion (0f, 90f, 0f, 0f);
    private Quaternion LampadaireRight = new Quaternion(0f, -90f, 0f, 0f);

    void Start()
    {
        Zpos = 10;
        StartCoroutine(SpawningLampadaire());
    }

    IEnumerator SpawningLampadaire()
    {
        for(; ;)
        {
            InstantiateTime -= 0.001f;
            Debug.Log("SpawningLampadaire");
            Instantiate(Lampadaire, new Vector3(4.55f, 0.17f, Zpos), LampadaireLeft);
            Debug.Log("SpawningLampadaire2");
            Instantiate(Lampadaire, new Vector3(-4.55f, 0.17f, Zpos), LampadaireRight);
            Zpos += 40;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(InstantiateTime);
        }
    }

}
```

I looked again and again to make sure I have written it well, I tried to directly write the Quaternion in the function, but nothing works. 
It would be amazing if you could help me guys. Thanks a lot. Have a nice evening.

Comment: Are you sure the script is attached on an **active** gameObject, **in the scene** when the game starts? By the way, change `new Quaternion(0f, -90f, 0f, 0f)` by `Quaternion.Euler(0f, -90f, 0f)`

Comment: Does the object not show up in the game hierarchy?

Have you defined the Lampadaire object in the inspector?

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: Yes, the script is attached to an active GameObject. In the scene.
The object I try to instantiate doesn't show up in the game hierarchy. I have defined it in the inspector, and I don't get any errors in the console.
:/

Comment: I copied your exact script and it worked as anticipated, so I'm afraid the issue is not in your code.

Comment: @Azuoo Can you please share a screenshot of your inspector configuration for this class?

Comment: https://imgur.com/j90ptPO
I really don't know what to do :/

Comment: Have you checked that the Lampadaire is still set in the inspector when the game is running?

Comment: I'm getting PTSD from the for-loop with no exit condition. Please, for the love of the flying spagetti monster, be at least civilized enough to use `while(true)` for your infinite loops like a normal person. xD

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I recreated a new project, and it works. It don't know where it comes from. Thanks for the help guys.